# Arreglos, numeros aleatorios y comparar

Tags: java, array, comparaciones

Ocupo ayuda, tengo que realizar un programa que llene dos arreglos con números aleatorios, luego compare sume dos números de un arreglo y los compare con la suma del segundo, e indique cual es el número mayor.

El problema es que no comprendo bien como realizar la primera parte, he tratado de generar un código de números aleatorios pero no se como guardarlo en el arreglo.

Código para el aleatorio:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        Random generadorAleatorios = new Random();

        int numeroAleatorio = 1 + generadorAleatorios.nextInt(14);


            System.out.println(numeroAleatorio);
        }
```

Luego para compararlos tengo este código:

```
Double compNumeros[];// arreglo para comparar numeros
    compNumeros = new Double[10];
        System.out.println("");// para dejar un espacio en pantalla
        try {
            System.out.println("Debe de ingresar 10 digitos decimales");
            for (int i = 0; i < compNumeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Digite el valor a ingresar:");
             compNumeros[i] = teclado.nextDouble();
             teclado.nextLine();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ingreso un dato erroneo");
            System.out.println("Vuelva a Iniciar el programa");
        }
        Double max, min;
        min = max = compNumeros[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < compNumeros.length; i++) {
            if (min > compNumeros[i]) {
                min = compNumeros[i];                
                }
            if (max < compNumeros[i]) {
                max = compNumeros[i];

            }
            System.out.println("Segun el analisis realizado, los datos son los siguientes:");
            System.out.println("El Numero Mayor ingresado es: " + max);
            System.out.println("El Numero Minimo Ingresado es: " + min);
            System.out.println("Fin del Programa");
```

Peero tengo problemas con la parte de de como guardar en los arreglos.

Les agradezco me puedan orientar

Answer (score 1):

Amigo para poder hacer que el vector sea de números aleatorios puedes usar tu misma función, pero te aconsejo que uses este otro método del la clase Math:

```
    double[] arreglo1 = new double[10];
    double[] arreglo2 = new double[10];
    int valorEntero = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo1.length; i++) {
               //para conseguir un número entero entre M y N con M menor
               //que N y ambos incluídos, debes usar esta fórmula
               valorEntero = Math.floor(Math.random()*(N-M+1)+M);
               //Luego debes incluir ese numero aleatorio en el vector
               arreglo1[i] = valorEntero;

               valorEntero = Math.floor(Math.random()*(N-M+1)+M);
               //Luego debes incluir ese numero aleatorio en el vector
               arreglo2[i] = valorEntero;
        }

        //loops para hacer la suma de cada arreglo
        int suma1 = 0;
        int suma2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < arreglo1.length; i++){

            suma1 += arreglo1[i];
            suma2 += arreglo2[i];


        }

    //condicional para ver cual es mayor

        if(suma1 < suma2){

            System.out.println("El arreglo1 es mayor con la suma de:" + suma1 );

        }else if(suma 1 > suma2){

            System.out.println("El arreglo2 es mayor con la suma de:" + suma2);
        }else {

            System.out.println("los dos arreglos dan la misma suma");
        }
```

No te entendi muy bien lo demas, comentame y te seguire ayudando

Comment: no te entendi lo de sume 2 numeros del arreglo y comparelo con el otro, no te entendi eso, si es 2 numeros de un arreglo con 2 numeros del otro arreglo o simplemente como se entiende, ¿2 de un arreglo con todos los del otro arreglo?

Comment: Buenas Asdrubal, si la idea es tener dos arreglos que se llenen de forma aleatoria con numeros y se comparen para indicar cual de los dos es el mayor.

Comment: vale ya edito la respuesta completa